# Java Optional - If Else Statements

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, option-type

So after some reading I've seen that

```
if (optional.isPresent()) {
    //do smth
}
```

is not the preferred way to use Optional (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html). But if I have an if-statement like this:

```
if (optional.isPresent()) {
    car = getCar(optional.get());
} else {
    car = new Car();
    car.setName(carName);
}
```

Is this the best way to do this or is there a more recommended way?

Comment: I doubt you even need the if statements, it kind of defies the whole point.

Comment: @assylias How does that work? The return of the optional would be an id and not a Car object?

Comment: Actually it is wrapper introduced to indicate to the developer that there can be an absense of returned value from some methods and he should take extra consideration.

Comment: @uraza I misread your code - apologies.

Comment: what's the logic on java not including this ability with `OptionalXXX` like `OptionalDouble`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use `Optional` as following.

```
Car car = optional.map(id -> getCar(id))
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                Car c = new Car();
                c.setName(carName);
                return c;
            });
```

Writing with `if-else` statement is imperative style and it requires the variable `car` to be declared before `if-else` block.

Using `map` in `Optional` is more functional style. And this approach doesn't need variable declaration beforehand and is recommended way of using `Optional`.

Comment: This does indeed seem to work. However, I do wonder if that makes the code any more readable or if there is any advantage in writing it this way.

Answer (score 10):

If you can incorporate the name into the `Car` constructor, then you can write this:

```
car = optional.map(id -> getCar(id))
              .orElseGet(() -> new Car(carName));
```

If you must call the setter separately from your constructor, you would end up with something like this:

```
car = optional.map(id -> getCar(id))
              .orElseGet(() -> {
                  Car c = new Car();
                  c.setName(carName);
                  return c;
              });
```

Comment: Does orElseGet really return a Car object if the Optional is not empty?

Comment: If `Car` has a constructor with parameter `carName`, `car = optional.orElse(new Car(carName));` could be used.

Comment: it looks like, the `Op` is using `getCar` method to get `car` rather than just from `Optional`.

Comment: Consider using the builder pattern

Answer (score 4):

To take it further, if you have multiple `if (optional.isPresent())` or `if (obj != null)`

You can do this:

(getN returns `Optional<Car>`)

```
return get1().map(Optional::of)
.orElseGet(() -> get2()).map(Optional::of)
.orElseGet(() -> get3()).map(Optional::of);
```

I.e. would be like this using `if` statements

```
Optional<Car> car = get1();
if (car.isPresent()){
  return car;
}
car = get2();
if (car.isPresent()){
  return car;
}
car = get3();
if (car.isPresent()){
  return car;
}
return Optional.empty();
```

Comment: Just note that if `getN()` can return a null value, you have to wrap it in `Optional.ofNullable` and that can become quite heavy to read : 

`return Optional.ofNullable(get1()).map(Optional::of)
.orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(get2())).map(Optional::of)
.orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(get3())).map(Optional::of);`

Comment: Java 9 now has ```Optional#or``` which hides the ```orElseGet``` and ```map(Optional::of)``` logic

Answer (score 0):

```
Car car = optional.ifPresentOrElse(
id -> getCar(id),
() -> {
    Car c = new Car();
    c.setName(carName);
    return c;
};
```

);

This doesn't seem to work since ifPresentOrElse is void method, it won't return anything

Comment: As the OP who posted the comment said that this seem to work, if you have any supporting reason why this will not work and what will work, please add in your answer.

Comment: Tysvm for adding this answer. I happened to need this in a testing context. While I had noticed the `.ifPresent()` method, I had missed this perfect imperative solution of `.ifPresentOrElse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Optional API update. You can use `or()` method if you want to return return an Optional describing the value, otherwise returns an Optional produced by the supplying function.

For instance

```
private <T> Optional<T> getSetting(Integer Id, String country) {
    return repo.findByIdAndCountry(id, country,)
         .or(() -> repo.findDefaultByCountry(country))
         .or(() -> repo.findGlobalDefault());
}
```

The `or()` method description

```
/**
 * If a value is present, returns an {@code Optional} describing the value,
 * otherwise returns an {@code Optional} produced by the supplying function.
 *
 * @param supplier the supplying function that produces an {@code Optional}
 *        to be returned
 * @return returns an {@code Optional} describing the value of this
 *         {@code Optional}, if a value is present, otherwise an
 *         {@code Optional} produced by the supplying function.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the supplying function is {@code null} or
 *         produces a {@code null} result
 * @since 9
 */
public Optional<T> or(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(supplier);
    if (isPresent()) {
        return this;
    } else {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Optional<T> r = (Optional<T>) supplier.get();
        return Objects.requireNonNull(r);
    }
}
```